# how to force build vendored gems in rails 3.01 - rmagick issue when vendored

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

I have vendored rmagick and its not behaving. Works fine when not vendored, but when vendoring using:

```
gem unpack rmagick --target vendor/gems

Fetching: rmagick-2.13.1.gem (100%)
Unpacked gem: '/Users/joelnylund/Projects/aras/vendor/gems/rmagick-2.13.1'
```

Then When I try to load my server I get:

```
/Users/joelnylund/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require': no such file to load -- RMagick2.so (LoadError)
```

I used to do "rake gems:build:force" to fix this on rails 2.3.5, but this gives me the same error now. How do I tell rails 3 to native build the vendored gem?

Similar question, but no answer here:
[no such file to load -- RMagick2.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169178/no-such-file-to-load-rmagick2-so)

Comment: Rails' handling of gems with binary components is sub-par at best. Doing it manually is not that hard. Try: `cd /Users/joelnylund/Projects/aras/vendor/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick && ruby extconf.rb && make && mv RMagick2.* ../../lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run `rake gems:build` ?

Comment: yes, see above build force doesnt work, build doesnt build them.